# Better solution for register/login

Tags: login, experience, register

when you are on a site or a blog do you prefer register/login using a classic form with first name, last name, email etc or do you prefer register/login using something like google, facebook, twitter etc..? Which is the best?

Comment: A lot depends on context, how technically oriented the users are, how security conscious they are and many other factors. Arguably the best thing is to offer both and let users decide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the security consideration. I prefer to login with Google instead of fill in form manually (name, email, password) especially we’re not sure the app has enough resources to make sure the security.

Login with Google allow the app to generate a token that contain information which they will use to verify you as a user.

As a designer we can give multiple option here.

Answer (score 3):

*There is no best single option. Multiple registration options is a de facto standard now.*

E.g. a concise classic form and Facebook, Twitter, etc.